# cannot connect to local server from ip address?

Tags: port-forwarding, dhcp, nat, airport-extreme

I am trying to hit a local server running on my macbook pro from an external device (iphone/ipad), but am unable to.

I have an airport extreme, and so going I followed these instructions:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3491782?start=0&tstart=0

I went to airport utility under Network, I have added a DHCP reservation, reserved by MAC address.  I put in the wifi mac address for my computer, and the IP address given by the DHCP lease (192.168.1.5).

I then went under port settings, and added an entry:
    Public TCP port: 3000
    Private IP address: 192.168.1.5
    Private TCP port: 3000

...

I still cannot access my sever.  Even from my macbook pro, if instead of going to localhost:3000, if I go to http://192.168.1.5:3000 I get:

> This site can’t be reached 192.168.1.5 refused to connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The IP address and MAC address is NOT that of your Mac. It is that of the server running in the virtual machine. Nothing is needed on the airport, and it is actually dangerous what you did because that is opening the outside world to your server. Find the IP address and MAC address of the virtual NIC on the server. That's what you are looking for.

Comment: Ahh. ok I see, by default my web server was binding to localhost, and that's why it did not work.  I changed that to my macbook's IP, and now it works!  Thank you!!

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was saying, but I misunderstood your question and assumed this was a "virtual server." Glad you got it figured out.